# Smarty show last 4 articles

Tags: php, smarty

I use SMARTY and when I want to show the last 4 articles, it shows me 4 articles but not the last one (penultimate - second last). When I add one more article, then its show me the last one (but now not last one :D)

This is the end of my SQL code from taking data from database:

```
FROM cms_article AS a 
JOIN cms_detail_of_page AS d ON d.idOfDetailOfPage = a.idOfDetailOfPage 
JOIN cms_page AS p ON p.idOfPage = d.idOfPage
WHERE a.idOfLanguage = '" . $this->language . "' AND isArticleVisible = 1
ORDER BY publicationDateOfArticle DESC, timestampOfArticle DESC 
LIMIT 5"
```

This is my PHP Smarty code:

```
<div class="items">
{foreach $recentArticles as $article name=a}
    {if !$smarty.foreach.a.first}
    <div class="col50">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="/{$language}/{$article.url}/"> <img src="uploads/photogallery/preserve.php?filename={$article.image}" alt="{$article.headline}" style="width:560px; height:300px;">
                <span class="date">{$article.timestamp|date_format:"%d/%m/%Y"}</span>
                <span class="box">
                    <span class="category">{$article.parent}</span>
                    <h3>{$article.headline}</h3>
                    <p>{$article.preview|truncate:100}</p>
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {/if}
{/foreach}
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I think problem is with this one:

```
 {if !$smarty.foreach.a.first}
```

But when I delete the !, its show my only last article (not last 4 articles).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fetching 5 articles from DB and your IF statement skips the first result. Change your query to `LIMIT 4` or change `foreach`

```
{foreach $recentArticles as $article name=a}
    {if $smarty.foreach.a.iteration < 5}
        <div class="col50">
            <div class="item">
                <a href="/{$language}/{$article.url}/"> <img src="uploads/photogallery/preserve.php?filename={$article.image}" alt="{$article.headline}" style="width:560px; height:300px;">
                    <span class="date">{$article.timestamp|date_format:"%d/%m/%Y"}</span>
                    <span class="box">
                        <span class="category">{$article.parent}</span>
                        <h3>{$article.headline}</h3>
                        <p>{$article.preview|truncate:100}</p>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your articles are ordered in a reverse order, so the first one is actually the last one.
That `{if !$smarty.foreach.a.first}` means "do not show this if it is the first one"
Just remove it and the `{/if}`

Comment: This solution work fine, but its show my 6 articles.. but i have LIMIT 5? How is it possible? All my LIMITS are on 5, but still show 6 articles (i have more on DB).